# Matching strings to boolean values in Algolia Search

Tags: angularjs, algolia

I am working on an e-commerce where products are mainly splitted in two categories: non-premium and premium. I have used a boolean value in the indexing process to determine if one product is or is not premium.

I'd like to make that whenever a user searches for "premium", only premium products are shown.

How am I able to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a workaround to do this, however I must say that it's not really my favourite one.

I basically store in a single array a list of every single tag I index, and I build the filters depending on what's being written in the query.

```js
// [...] code containing the initialization of algolia-client-js

var tags = ["premium"];

function formatFilters(parameters) {

  var filters = {
    numeric: [],
    tags: [],
    query: parameters.query || ""
  };

  angular.forEach(parameters.ranges, function(value, key) {
    filters.numeric.push(key + ">=" + value.from, key + "<=" + value.to);
  });

  angular.forEach(filters.query.split(" "), function(value, key) {
    if (tags.indexOf(value) > -1) {
      filters.tags.push(value);
      filters.query = filters.query.replace(value, "").trim();
    }
  });

  return filters;
}

filters = formatFilters({ ranges: [], query: "premium iphone" });
console.log(filters);

function search(parameters, clearHits) {
  var index        = client.initIndex(parameters.order.id);
  var builtFilters = formatFilters(parameters);

  return index.search(
    builtFilters.query,
    {
      numericFilters: builtFilters.numeric,
      tagFilters: builtFilters.tags
    }
  );
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I think that's the easiest way to go 